# Change 'while' by 'foreach' in 'mysql_fetch_row' in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Is it possible to change `while` by `foreach` in `mysql_fetch_row` in PHP?

For example

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

This will take all records(rows) from query `SELECT * FROM test`.

But, if foreach is used

```
foreach (mysql_fetch_row($result) as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

This will take only first record(row) from query `SELECT * FROM test`.

Is it possible get all records by `foreach` loop  when using with `mysql_fetch_row` ?

Comment: You could use a framework such as codeigniter

Comment: @RPM, what's that got to do with anything?

Comment: Because it handles what your trying to do. Actually nevermind. You're trying to get all rows, without specifying their column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `foreach` if:

- you create a class that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) or [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), or
- you obtain the whole result set in an array and use that array with `foreach`.

You *could* use a `for` loop, but the code would be less than readable:

```
for ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result); $row !== false; $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Should be `Iterator` instead of `ArrayAccess`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, both `ArrayAccess` and `Iterator` can be used with `foreach`. Updated answer.

Comment: But `ArrayAcces` does not give you control on order of kes/values and skips protected/private properties, and fails completely when using internal array (or resource in this case) as data holder instead of class properties, so it can give different results when accessing as array and iterating with foreach, so to have true iterable object, better use `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because `foreach` needs a array. Here, [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) returns only one row at a time.

Comment: It is possible with `for` loop